# Magento 2: Unable to unserialize value. Error: Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded

Tags: catalogsearch, frontend-error, magento2.2.8, unserialize

I am getting Bellow Error when i try to search default Magento search 
https://temp.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=Hiper

```
Unable to unserialize value. Error: Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded
```

Error Log:

> {"0":"Unable to unserialize value. Error: Control character error,
>   possibly incorrectly encoded","1":"#1
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements() called at
>   [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:89]\n#2
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:129]\n#3
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
>   called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php:55]\n#4
>   Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called
>   at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:65]\n#5
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php:208]\n#6
>   Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->build() called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php:218]\n#7
>   Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->publicBuild() called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/App/View.php:170]\n#8
>   Magento\Framework\App\View->loadLayoutUpdates() called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/App/View.php:114]\n#9
>   Magento\Framework\App\View->loadLayout() called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Controller/Result/Index.php:119]\n#10
>   Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index->getCacheableResult(&Magento\CatalogSearch\Helper\Data#000000006a20343000000000593f6e54#,
>   &Magento\Search\Model\Query#000000006a20342000000000593f6e54#)
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Controller/Result/Index.php:91]\n#11
>   Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index->execute() called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]\n#12
>   Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('execute',
>   array()) called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]\n#13
>   Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
>   called at
>   [app/code/Zemez/AjaxCatalog/Plugin/CatalogSearch/Result.php:34]\n#14
>   Zemez\AjaxCatalog\Plugin\CatalogSearch\Result->aroundExecute(&Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index\Interceptor#000000006a20351000000000593f6e54#,
>   &Closure#000000006a20343d00000000593f6e54#) called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]\n#15
>   Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]\n#16
>   Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('execute',
>   array(), NULL) called at
>   [generated/code/Magento/CatalogSearch/Controller/Result/Index/Interceptor.php:26]\n#17
>   Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index\Interceptor->execute()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:107]\n#18
>   Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000006a20377800000000593f6e54#)
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]\n#19
>   Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch',
>   array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000006a20377800000000593f6e54#))
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]\n#20
>   Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000006a20377800000000593f6e54#)
>   called at
>   [app/code/Bss/Paymentshipping/Plugin/App/Action/Context.php:81]\n#21
>   Bss\Paymentshipping\Plugin\App\Action\Context->aroundDispatch(&Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index\Interceptor#000000006a20351000000000593f6e54#,
>   &Closure#000000006a20351300000000593f6e54#,
>   &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000006a20377800000000593f6e54#)
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]\n#22
>   Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000006a20377800000000593f6e54#)
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]\n#23
>   Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
>   array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000006a20377800000000593f6e54#),
>   NULL) called at
>   [generated/code/Magento/CatalogSearch/Controller/Result/Index/Interceptor.php:39]\n#24
>   Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000006a20377800000000593f6e54#)
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:55]\n#25
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000006a20377800000000593f6e54#)
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]\n#26
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch',
>   array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000006a20377800000000593f6e54#))
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]\n#27
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000006a20377800000000593f6e54#)
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php:94]\n#28 Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor#000000006a2036ae00000000593f6e54#,
>   &Closure#000000006a2036a600000000593f6e54#,
>   &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000006a20377800000000593f6e54#)
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]\n#29
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000006a20377800000000593f6e54#)
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php:73]\n#30
>   Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor#000000006a2036ae00000000593f6e54#,
>   &Closure#000000006a2036a600000000593f6e54#,
>   &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000006a20377800000000593f6e54#)
>   called at
>   [app/code/Zemez/SiteMaintenance/Model/PageCache/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php:30]\n#31
>   Zemez\SiteMaintenance\Model\PageCache\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor#000000006a2036ae00000000593f6e54#,
>   &Closure#000000006a2036a600000000593f6e54#,
>   &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000006a20377800000000593f6e54#)
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]\n#32
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000006a20377800000000593f6e54#)
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]\n#33
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
>   array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000006a20377800000000593f6e54#),
>   NULL) called at
>   [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]\n#34
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000006a20377800000000593f6e54#)
>   called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:136]\n#35
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at
>   [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]\n#36
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:257]\n#37
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#000000006a20373600000000593f6e54#)
>   called at
>   [index.php:41]\n</pre>","url":"/catalogsearch/result/?q=hyperline","script_name":"/index.php"}

Magento version 2.2.8

any one have idea how to fixed it ?

Comment: check Ref: https://magecomp.com/blog/solved-unable-to-unserialize-value-magento-2-2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve this issue by flushing my Redis Cache from by running following commands

```
redis-cli 
flushall
```

I hope this works.

**EDIT**

try this
https://www.scommerce-mage.com/blog/solved-unable-to-unserialize-value-magento-2.html

Comment: see my updated answer wish if it works for you

Comment: @ASQ, Please update the fll command like php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: I didn't understand which commands?

Comment: I am about redis-cli 
flushall commands. Why because, when we run these commands, it shows not defined command

Comment: These commands are used to flush redis cache

Answer (score 0):

Go to this file location and paste below code and best way try to override this file : **/vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php**

```
public function utf8ize( $mixed ) {
    if (is_array($mixed)) foreach ($mixed as $key => $value) $mixed[$key] = $this->utf8ize($value);
    elseif (is_string($mixed)) return mb_convert_encoding($mixed, "UTF-8", "UTF-8");
    return $mixed;
}

public function serialize($data){
    $result = json_encode( $this->utf8ize( $data ) );
    if (false === $result) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Unable to serialize value. Error: " . json_last_error_msg());
    }
    return $result;
}
```

### How to override this file

*The preference for the SerializerInterface was added since 2.2.x version of the Magento, and declared in the `app/etc/di.xml`:*

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface" type="Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json" />
```

> Override Hint

***Then create the class [Vendor][Module]\Serialize\Serializer\Json that extends Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json and make your changes in there.***

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this article](https://docs.web357.com/article/55-solved-error-decoding-json-data-control-character-error-possibly-incorrectly-encoded#:%7E:text=This%20error%20means%20that%20you,breaks%20during%20saving%20the%20data.&text=1.) to solve out an issue

This error means that you don't have enough space in the MySql column "params", of the table "#__extensions", to save all the required parameters that the Cookies Policy Notification Bar needs, and the json data breaks during saving the data.

**change the type of the column "params" from "TEXT" to "LONGTEXT"**
[image]