# Getting this error "This page isn’t working HTTP ERROR 500"

Tags: magento2, http-error-500

Please help, how to find error log and fix

Magento 2.3.2

This page isn’t working
domainname.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Open app/bootstrap.php and uncomment #ini_set('display_errors', 1), it should be as ini_set('display_errors', 1)
 then reload the page, you may get the actual error on your screen. Also ensure if you are running Magento with developer mode. Command: php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

Comment: @HimmatPaliwal Thank you.

Comment: @HimmatPaliwal Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Unable to unserialize value. Error: Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded in /home/sbaelect/domains/sbaelectric.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php:39 Stack trace: #0

Comment: Which version of Magento you are using?

Comment: @HimmatPaliwal Magento 2.3.2

Comment: Follow below link: https://magecomp.com/blog/solved-unable-to-unserialize-value-magento-2-2/ Overwrite the class in your module. Don't update directly in vendor files.

Comment: @HimmatPaliwal Thank, but not work. Check this https://sbaelectric.com/

Comment: uncomment `#ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in `app/bootstrap.php` and see the error, or check the logs in the `var/logs/` folder

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by Flushing my Redis Cache from the CLI

Solution1:

```
redis-cli flushall
```

Solution2 : check with this file and find function and update with below code :

/vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php

```
public function unserialize($string)
{
    if($this->is_serialized($string))
    {
        $string = $this->serialize($string);
    }
    $result = json_decode($string, true);
    if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
         throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Unable to unserialize value.');

    }
    return $result;
}
```

and add function to check if string is serialized:

```
function is_serialized($value, &$result = null)
{
    // Bit of a give away this one
    if (!is_string($value))
    {
        return false;
    }
    // Serialized false, return true. unserialize() returns false on an
    // invalid string or it could return false if the string is serialized
    // false, eliminate that possibility.
    if ($value === 'b:0;')
    {
        $result = false;
        return true;
    }
    $length = strlen($value);
    $end    = '';
    switch ($value[0])
    {
        case 's':
            if ($value[$length - 2] !== '"')
            {
                return false;
            }
        case 'b':
        case 'i':
        case 'd':
            // This looks odd but it is quicker than isset()ing
            $end .= ';';
        case 'a':
        case 'O':
            $end .= '}';
            if ($value[1] !== ':')
            {
                return false;
            }
            switch ($value[2])
            {
                case 0:
                case 1:
                case 2:
                case 3:
                case 4:
                case 5:
                case 6:
                case 7:
                case 8:
                case 9:
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        case 'N':
            $end .= ';';
            if ($value[$length - 1] !== $end[0])
            {
                return false;
            }
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    if (($result = @unserialize($value)) === false)
    {
        $result = null;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I do 
solution 1 : I got this "-bash: redis-cli: command not found"

Comment: solution 2 : not work, check this https://sbaelectric.com/

Comment: check this one - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/285750/magento-2-unable-to-unserialize-value-error-control-character-error-possibly